# how to get number of day (as in year) from a date in php example if it date is 20/2/1998 ans will be 51.?

Tags: php

How can I get the number of day **(from date's year)** from date?

**Example:**
If the input date is 20/2/1998 then the answer should be 51. 
Also we need to consider the leap year.

THANK YOU

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try date and strtotime?

Comment: yes but i think i done it wrong. can you do for me pls?

Comment: Please be more specific: what you tried and what you've "done wrong".

Comment: You should always include your tries in your question. It gives a starting point for us and makes it easier for you later since we can use the same variable names as you do, meaning you can just copy paste. Now I may have used other variable names which means you have to change them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, you should try this :-

```
date("z", strtotime("20-2-1998")) + 1;
```

**Note** :- The format characer `z` gives you day of the year which is starting from 0 to 365. So you've to add `+1` for exact day.

Comment: I'm sorry for this, both of you have a much better answer but I can't delete my answer. I have upvoted both of your answers in the meantime.

Comment: @Andreas Its okay. Just update your answer with an alternative and include my answer to it. So it will be helpful to others also.

Comment: I really don't like using other people's answers. But I have another idea.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
$date = '20/2/1998';

$explode = explode('/', $date);
$implode = implode('/', array_reverse($explode));

$day = date('z', strtotime($implode)) + 1;
echo $day; // 51
```

Thanks to @Yash Parekh for the +1 note

Comment: I'm sorry for this, both of you have a much better answer but I can't delete my answer. I have upvoted both of your answers in the meantime.